# How to convert milliseconds to date in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in MongoDB and documents like this -

```
[
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1428907779206,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9789877667",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9189877667",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9189877000",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 8,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9189877010",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 8,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Mumbai",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9180877010",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Mumbai",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9180877010",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Mumbai",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1429986600000,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "91808770101",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1429986600000,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "91808070101",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1429986600000,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "91808070101",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 8,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Jaipur",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9180877010",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 8,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "UP-West",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1430111514796,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "9180877010",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    },
    {
        "campaignId": 1,
        "operatorId": 1,
        "txnType": "DR",
        "circle": "Delhi",
        "amount": 2,
        "balance": 0,
        "txnTime": 1429986601111,
        "txnSrc": "Dial_In",
        "msisdn": "91808070101",
        "smsContent": "Hello Mr Arif"
    }
]
```

I made a aggregation query for group by for this collection on the basis of unique msisdn for a date, which is -

```
     db.campaign_wallet.aggregate({
   "$match": {
     "campaignId": 1,
     "txnTime": {
       "$gte": 1429554600000,
       "$lte": 1430159400000
     }
   }
 }, {
   "$group": {
     "_id": {
       "txnTime": "$txnTime",
       "msisdn": "$msisdn"
     },
     "msisdnCount": {
       "$sum": 1
     }
   }
 }, {
   "$group": {
     "_id": "$_id.txnTime",
     "msisdns": {
       "$push": {
         "txnTime": "$_id.txnTime",
         "count": "$msisdnCount"
       },
     },
     "count": {
       "$sum": "$msisdnCount"
     }
   }
 });
```

This is giving right result on the basis of time in milliseconds and msisdns -

[image: Query Result]

I have to convert time(milliseconds) in date in my query so that it will filter data on the basis of date not on exact time in milliseconds. What is the solution?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what you actual problem is.

Comment: @Philipp   I edited question. I want to change time miliseconds to date in the mongodb aggregation query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding the milliseconds time to a zero-milliseconds Date() object in the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator using the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) arithmetic operator, so an aggregation pipeline like the following will give you the timestamp field converted to Date:

```
db.campaign_wallet.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "campaignId" : 1 , 
            "txnTime" : { 
                "$gte" : 1429554600000 , 
                "$lte" : 1430159400000
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : "$txnTime",
                "msisdn":"$msisdn"
            }, 
            "msisdnCount" : { "$sum" : 1}
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$_id.txnTime", 
            "msisdns" : { 
                "$push" :{
                    "txnTime" : "$_id.txnTime", 
                    "count" : "$msisdnCount"
                },
            }, 
            "count" : { 
                "$sum" : "$msisdnCount"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$msisdns"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "msisdns": {
                "txnTime" : {
                    "$add": [ new Date(0), "$msisdns.txnTime" ]
                }
            },
            "msisdns.count": 1,
            "count": 1
         } 
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1430111514796,
            "msisdns" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:11:54.796Z"),
                "count" : 1
            },
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1430111514900,
            "msisdns" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:11:54.900Z"),
                "count" : 1
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @AmitDas I simply copied your aggregation pipeline, added the `$unwind` and `$project` pipeline stages and ran it against the sample documents that you provided in your question above, got those results with the timestamp field converted. Are you running it against a sample/test collection? Perhaps the `$match` query is not filtering the documents correctly? I really am not sure at this point what might be causing the wrong result.

Comment: @AmitDas I have completely missed your point since you are now asking for a different thing altogether here. In your comment reply to Phillip, you said _I want to change time miliseconds to date in the mongodb aggregation query_ and the answer I gave addresses that, can you please be more explicit or clearer with your question?