# How to find the data by specific month in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a4212b49e710765c486d7c6"), 
  "student_id" : ObjectId("5a3df85bcc6425291c54d2ad"), 
  "attendance_status" : true, 
  "create_at" : 1514279592137.0, 
  "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a4212b49e710765c486d7c7"), 
  "student_id" : ObjectId("5a3df85bcc6425291c54d2ae"), 
  "attendance_status" : true, 
  "create_at" : 1514279592137.0, 
  "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a4212b49e710765c486d7c9"), 
  "student_id" : ObjectId("5a3df85bcc6425291c54d2b0"), 
  "attendance_status" : true, 
  "create_at" : 1514279592137.0, 
  "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I store the creation time as times tramp. I want to get a data based on creation month.how to achieve it?

I am trying to find the data using the following query.

```
  Attendance.aggregate(
  [{
      $project: {
        create_at: "$create_at",
        student_id: "$student_id",
        attendance_status: "$attendance_status",
        month: {
          $month: "$create_at"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "month": req.body.month
      }
    },
 ])
```

I want to the output based on the create month. If i send the **req.body.month=3**.I want the data in 3 month only.

Comment: can you be more specific about the question? what library are you using to query mongodb? what is the expected output? example would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds to date in mongodb aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889719/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation)

Answer (score 4):

For whatever month you want to query the data for, you can get start timestamp(s) and the end timestamp(e) by using `new Date('YYYY-MM-DD').getTime()`and query the db as

```
Attendance.find(
    {
     create_at: {
         $gte: s, //$gte corresponds to >=
         $lte: e  //$lte corresponds to <=
        }
    }
)
```

You can find more details about such mongo operators [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)

Answer (score 0):

Do to that, I think you should see [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

Exemple :

```
var moment = require('moment');
var month = 3; // March

// Find all documents between 2017/03/01 and 2017/03/31
Attendance.find({
    create_at: {
        $gte: moment(`2017/${month}`, 'YYYY/MM').startOf('month').format('x'),
        $lte: moment(`2017/${month}`, 'YYYY/MM').endOf('month').format('x')
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm getting "MongoError: can't convert from BSON type double to Date" this error.

Comment: You still using aggregate ? Or are you using find request ?

Comment: using aggregate

Comment: @Sakthivel what did you do bout that error `MongoError: can't convert from BSON type double to Date`? Im also using `aggregate`